# Login the user with Facebook without revealing the APP ID

Tags: facebook

In the Facebook documentation about Login the user with Facebook APP they say:

"*Because it requires you to include your App Secret you should not attempt to make this call client-side as that would expose this secret to all your app users. It is important that your App Secret is never shared with anyone*".

I understend it is about APP Secret, but what about the Developer ID?
The developer ID is added in the URL address of the window for login the user with Facebook:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=...&state=...&scope=...`

The APP_ID can be copied and used by anyone.
I tryed with JavaScript SDK, and with PHP SDK, but in both cases the developer ID appears in the address bar.
I tryed also the get and display the page from that URL address using cURL, but of course not works.
Is there any way to login the users in my web site using Facebook, without revealing the developer ID?
Or, it doesn't matter if someone uses your Facebook APP ID?

Answer (score 1):

you could try using iframes? not a very good solution for the problem because it's still very much available but at least it's not in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, this is essentially public information.